# Why are commercial PPA updates suddenly very slow?

Tags: apt, ppa

When using apt-get update from terminal, I can see process come to a grinding halt when the commercial PPAs are updating.

In hoping that this isn't intentional, is there a fix to get apt-get update working faster with commercial PPAs?

- I don't want to remove the commercial PPAs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Slowdowns occasionally happen because all PPA's are hosted only on Canonical/Launchpad's servers in the UK and are not mirrored around the world like the official repositories.
- Right now, the Canonical servers are under extremely heavy load because of the recent release of 12.04.1 and all the people on 10.04 LTS who are now upgrading to it. (Automatic upgrades from 10.04 were not possible until 12.04.1 was available)
- There's no fix *right now*, but speeds should be back to normal within the next few days as the load decreases.
- If you use `apt-get` for package management, you may want to try the [*apt-fast*](http://www.mattparnell.com/projects/apt-fast-and-axel-roughly-26x-faster-apt-get-installations-and-upgrades.html) alternative which will probably download the PPAs faster (it uses multiple connections to the server).

Comment: In my case, the updating of private ppa's are normally very slow compared to all ppa's that come before. But, I am located in Australia, so the distance from servers makes sense. I am looking forward to when Canonical gets some good mirrors around the globe. Also, I took advice for apt-fast.. very handy, helped slightly and made everything else faster.

Comment: All PPAs are private; PPA=Personal Private Archive :)

Comment: Ah I see. :) I ment ppa's from purchased software.

Comment: Ah, I see too :) As far as I know, the commercial PPAs are on a special server which is probably unaffected.

Comment: Commercial PPAs. Mmm, excellently worded. Editing question to rectify. I think your first point still applies and answers the question, though.